# Single dash converted to double dash

Tags: plugins, functions, content

As the title says, if a single dash is used with a space between each side eg. 'Die Hard - Action Film' is written in to a WordPress post, once published it comes out as 'Die Hard -- Action Film'. If no spaces are used around the dash it works, but obviously this isn't desired.

I've obviously found out it's not something that happens with a default install of Wordpress but I can't seem to pinpoint what the cause is in my theme.

Comment: You will have to post what theme you are using, the plugins you are using and possibly your functions.php contents to be able to get the help you need.

Comment: there's probably something filtering the_content and doing some sort of swap. as Lyken said- start in your theme's functions.php file, look for any `add_filter('the_content','some_func')` calls.

Comment: Lyken, thank you so much. I decided to turn off a few plugins and found out the 'Smart YouTube' plugin was the culprit. Now I have to figure out if I can fix it or just drop the plugin all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's lines 396 - 398 in the smart youtube plugin's `smartyoutube.class.php` file:

```
function check($the_content, $side = 0)
{
    if (strpos($the_content, "httpv") !== false  ) 
    {
      $char_codes = array('&#215;', '&#8211;'); // <-- 8211 is an en dash
      $replacements = array("x", "--"); // <-- here's where it's swapping in --
      $the_content = str_replace($char_codes, $replacements, $the_content); // <--
```